# Playing two HTML 5 audio files simultaneously

Tags: html

Iam using HTML 5 audio for playing audio on my website. But I need the opportunity two play several audio files at once. But its not working.

1. Player a is running.
2. I start player b, but no sound.
3. I stop player a.
4. Now I can hear player b.

How can I solve this? Thanks! :)

Edit: Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <audio controls><source src="files/audio/meadow.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>
    <audio controls><source src="files/audio/blanket.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: without code, we can't help you.

Comment: I corrected it.